# I have a question regarding the Painlevé-Gullstrand (PG) metric with factor 2

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I have a question regarding the [Painlevé-Gullstrand (PG) metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gullstrand%E2%80%93Painlev%C3%A9_coordinates).

If we have the line element in a radial fall we get:

$$d\theta = d\phi = 0$$

$$ds^2 = -dT^2 + \left(dr+\sqrt{\frac{r_s}{r}}dT\right)^2.$$

Writing out the binomial formula we obtain:

$$ds^2 = -dT^2 + dr^2 + 2 \sqrt{\frac{r_s}{r}} dr dT + \frac{r_s}{r} dT^2.$$

If we now want to write down the metric tensor, we should obtain:

$$g_{\mu\nu} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\sqrt{\frac{r_s}{r}} \\
2\sqrt{\frac{r_s}{r}} & \frac{r_s}{r} -1\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

So am I right, that the factor 2 also comes into the metric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in general the differentials are not really "multiplication" as such (I can go into it if you'd like). So when you expand, you need to write

$$ds^2 = -dT^2 + dr^2 +  \underbrace{\sqrt{\frac{r_s}{r}} dr dT}_{g_{r
T}} + \underbrace{\sqrt{\frac{r_s}{r}}}_{g_{Tr}} dT dr + \frac{r_s}{r} dT^2 .$$

Answer (score 1):

You can write the line element with this general ansatz:

$ds^2=\begin{bmatrix}
   dT & dr \\
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   g_{00} & g_{01} \\
   g_{01} & g_{11} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   dT \\
   dr \\
 \end{bmatrix}
\qquad (1)$

The metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ must be symmetric!

from equation (1) we obtain :

$ds^2=g_{00} \,dT^2+2\,dT\,dr\,g_{01}+g_{11}\,dr^2$

Now compare the coefficients with your line element:

$g_{00}=\frac{r_s}{r}-1$

$2\,g_{01}=2\sqrt{\frac{r_s}{r}}$

$g_{01}=\sqrt{\frac{r_s}{r}}$

$g_{11}=1$

Answer (score 0):

No, the off-diagonal metric components are $g_{rT}=g_{Tr}=\sqrt{\frac{r_s}{r}}$ without a factor of 2.